# Why doesn't my Send button work?

Tags: android

I've created my first app, step by step, as described on

http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/starting-activity.html

According to this page, after clicking the button, there should appear a default "Hello world" layout, respectively the message typed in the text field.

Unfortunately, none of them appears at all. Absolutely nothing happens. Why?

Thanks in advance...

Comment: Because you made a mistake somewhere ...

Comment: Be sure your activity is in the manifest.

Comment: Please post your code so we can help you.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using setOnclicklistener. It seems you are new in coding. Google provide a good beginner guide. But still confusing a lot. take a look at this code.

first You need to locate your curret Button.

```
Button b1=(Button) findViewById(R.id.send);
```

assuming that your button hase a xml name"Send"

Now  starting activity by clicking button

```
b1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) 
                     {
                       Intent in=new Intent(MainActivity.this,secondActivity.class);
                       startActivity(in);   
        }
    });
    }
```

Assuming that "secondactivity" is your target activity which you want to open by clicking button. Another Putextra and getextra method will be same as described in tutorial. Note this is an alternative method which i have described but you can still use that one.
I suggest  that if you are a beginner you should start with youtube or lynda.com video tutorial. Rest is upon you

Answer (score 0):

Have you edited the AndroidManifest.xml file.You should make sure that the following code is in your manifest file:

```
<activity
        android:name="your package name.your main activity name"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />


        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```